# AMD Graphics card on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: ati, 15.10

Does anyone know when this issue will be fixed?  Without fglrx installed, I can boot to kernel 4.2, but can't use dual monitors.  I boot to kernel 3.18 on 15.10 and everything is fine.  I can't install AMD Catalyst 15.9 either (Install kernel headers using the command apt-get install linux-headers-3.19.0-31-generic.)

Comment: ***Bug reports*** and problems specific to development version of Ubuntu should be [reported on Launchpad](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) so that developers can see, track and fix these issues.  We do not assist in fixing bugs.

Comment: their latest update has fixed the issue, thank God!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let me point you at the **[Ubuntu 15.10 Wily Werewolf Release Notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WilyWerewolf/ReleaseNotes)**.  These release notes have a section about AMD cards and `fglrx` under the section which I've quoted below:

> ## Graphics and Display
>
> - AMD's **`fglrx`** driver does not work with the current kernel ([LP bug #1493888](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1493888)). It is warmly recommended to uninstall the `fglrx` driver before upgrading to Ubuntu 15.10. The open source **`radeon`** driver can be used as a temporary replacement until a fix is available.

There are known issues with the driver.  However, we do not handle bug triage here on Ask Ubuntu, and any type of fix needs to be done by AMD and provided to Ubuntu developers who have access to the packages (which is NOT everyone).

All you can do is wait here for a while, until it's fixed.  In the interim, use the `radeon` driver package instead.

Comment: I was aware of that information and did not know to post my question on Launchpad.  Thank you.